# How to Resolve deadlock on Apache Beehive HttpSessionMutexListener

Tags: apache, deadlock, beehive

I still using some old school framework (Apache Beehives) to develop my web portal application.

Apparently problem is happen more frequent nowadays, I suspect it is because we received more transactions and larger XML size on single requests.

I managed to found 2006's mailing list on beehive-user mailing list [here][1] is kinda framework's bug, but did anyone know whether the latest beehive versions already cover this situation?

Following, attached the sample deadlock thread dump.

```
> "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=10 tid=039fd000 nid=32 lwp_id=9764665 waiting on condition [44800000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <6abcd480> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:811)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:842)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1178)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:262)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowControlContainerImpl.beginContextOnPageFlow(PageFlowControlContainerImpl.java:68)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:328)
    - locked <6ad56a88> (a com.someprojects.somepackage.customer.portlets.myServicesHome.MyServicesController)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:64)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.ActionInterceptor.wrapAction(ActionInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.invoke(ActionInterceptors.java:50)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:58)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.ActionInterceptor.wrapAction(ActionInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.invoke(ActionInterceptors.java:50)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:58)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:87)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1199)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1129)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.executeAction(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:687)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.processActionInternal(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:142)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.PageFlowStubImpl.processAction(PageFlowStubImpl.java:107)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.NetuiActionHandler.raiseScopedAction(NetuiActionHandler.java:111)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:181)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:167)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.handlePostbackData(NetuiContent.java:225)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$2.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:180)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:324)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:130)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runInbound(Lifecycle.java:184)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:159)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:388)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:258)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:199)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:251)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.PortalServlet.service(PortalServlet.java:686)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at com.bea.portal.tools.servlet.http.HttpContextFilter.doFilter(HttpContextFilter.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at com.bea.p13n.servlets.PortalServletFilter.doFilter(PortalServletFilter.java:336)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3502)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2186)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2092)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '27' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=10 tid=04053200 nid=55 lwp_id=9764689 waiting for monitor entry [436bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.DeferredSessionStorageHandler.applyChanges(DeferredSessionStorageHandler.java:233)
    - waiting to lock <6ad56a88> (a com.someprojects.somepackage.customer.portlets.myServicesHome.MyServicesController)
    - locked <6abba0f8> (a org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.HttpSessionMutexListener$Mutex)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentStorageHandler.applyChanges(ScopedContentStorageHandler.java:73)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:863)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:502)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:432)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doInclude(RequestProcessor.java:1116)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.doForward(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:1757)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:1674)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.doActionForward(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2157)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowPageFilter.handleException(PageFlowPageFilter.java:487)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowPageFilter.runPage(PageFlowPageFilter.java:400)
    - locked <6ac29158> (a portlets.mymodifyBundle.ModifyBundleController)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowPageFilter.doFilter(PageFlowPageFilter.java:284)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:503)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:432)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.scoping.internal.ScopedRequestDispatcher.include(ScopedRequestDispatcher.java:119)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.JspContent.beginRender(JspContent.java:552)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.beginRender(NetuiContent.java:365)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$7.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:485)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:518)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:220)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:326)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.UIControl.render(UIControl.java:582)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.window.Content.beginRender(Content.java:322)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.ContentControlRenderer.beginRender(ContentControlRenderer.java:48)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$7.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:481)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:518)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:220)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:326)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.UIControl.render(UIControl.java:582)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.PresentationContext.render(PresentationContext.java:486)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.util.RenderToolkit.renderChild(RenderToolkit.java:146)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.jsp.taglib.skeleton.Child.doTag(Child.java:63)
    at jsp_servlet._framework._skeletons._customer.__flowlayout._jspService(__flowlayout.java:174)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:505)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:432)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.JspTools.renderJsp(JspTools.java:130)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.JspControlRenderer.beginRender(JspControlRenderer.java:72)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.PresentationControlRenderer.beginRender(PresentationControlRenderer.java:65)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$7.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:481)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:518)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:220)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:326)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.UIControl.render(UIControl.java:582)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.PresentationContext.render(PresentationContext.java:486)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.util.RenderToolkit.renderChild(RenderToolkit.java:146)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.jsp.taglib.skeleton.Child.doTag(Child.java:63)
    at jsp_servlet._framework._skeletons._customer.__gridlayout._jspService(__gridlayout.java:220)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:505)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:432)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.JspTools.renderJsp(JspTools.java:130)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.JspControlRenderer.beginRender(JspControlRenderer.java:72)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.application.laf.PresentationControlRenderer.beginRender(PresentationControlRenderer.java:65)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$7.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:481)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:518)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursiveRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:529)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:220)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runOutbound(Lifecycle.java:208)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:162)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:388)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:258)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doGet(UIServlet.java:211)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:196)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:251)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.PortalServlet.service(PortalServlet.java:686)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at com.bea.portal.tools.servlet.http.HttpContextFilter.doFilter(HttpContextFilter.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at com.bea.p13n.servlets.PortalServletFilter.doFilter(PortalServletFilter.java:336)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3502)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2186)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2092)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <6abcd480> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)


  [1]: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/beehive-user/200608.mbox/%3Cba6911de0608030910p24070ffem392ecbd07b692970@mail.gmail.com%3E "here"
```

Comment: How did you determine that it's a deadlock ?

Comment: Hi @11thdimension, 

as you can see on above thread dump-

thread-27 owned java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync while waiting com.someprojects.somepackage.customer.portlets.myServicesHome.MyServicesController

thread-4 locked com.someprojects.somepackage.customer.portlets.myServicesHome.MyServicesController while waiting java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync